# Installing Epson Stylus Office BX535WD scanner driver

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

I want to scan with my Epson Stylus Office BX535WD in Ubuntu 12.04 via USB cable but is doesn't.

Now I got on this site but there are so many files? Which ones should I download and install in order to scan? [Epson Support](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=21580&DSCCHK=ea245da3525f56d8ca2ab9408ed2d6d8b481d435)

Answer (score 0):

Updated the links for the latest driver.

To install the right driver, you need to download either of these 2 flies depending on your system architecture, 32bit(i386) or 64bit(amd64).

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb (for Ubuntu 64bit)     
epson-inkjet-printer-201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb (for Ubuntu 32bit)
```

You can download these files from [Here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16859&DSCCHK=7ace3f4ac22dba2019b7bac02a046f33b413343b)

Once you download the right file, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the download folder, and run the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>.deb
```

Comment: What do you mean with either of these 2 files?

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 64bit, then download the first file, and if you have Ubuntu 32bit then download the second file.

Comment: ygo@Ygo:~$ sudo dpkg -i iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package iscan.
(Reading database ... 527928 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking iscan (from iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iscan:
 iscan depends on iscan-data; however:
  Package iscan-data is not installed.

Comment: dpkg: error processing iscan (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iscan

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: Moreover when I try to install iscan-data this appears: ygo@Ygo:~$ sudo dpkg -i iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb
[sudo] password for ygo: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for ygo: 
Selecting previously unselected package iscan-data.
(Reading database ... 527972 files and directories currently installed.)

Comment: Unpacking iscan-data (from iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iscan-data:
 iscan-data depends on xsltproc; however:
  Package xsltproc is not installed.
dpkg: error processing iscan-data (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iscan-data

Comment: Try downloading this `201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb` [driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule), and let me know.

Comment: Clicking on that link wont show me a driver but the search module.

Comment: Moreover I installed xsltproc, then iscan-data and then iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb.

Comment: When you click on Accept you will get this [link](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16859&DSCCHK=7ace3f4ac22dba2019b7bac02a046f33b413343b) were you can download the driver.

Comment: But when push the scan buttton on the printer it says: Communication error, make sure the computer is connected, then try again

Comment: Just make sure that the machine is connected.  Sometimes you have to install the driver first, and then connect.

Comment: SHould I still install 201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ?

Comment: moreover printing works but when clicking on scan it says: connection error

Comment: What Ubuntu version did you download and install?  If the answer is 32bit then yes install 201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb. Otherwise install the other file.

Comment: Selecting previously unselected package epson-inkjet-printer-201106w.
(Reading database ... 528058 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-201106w (from epson-inkjet-printer-201106w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-201106w:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201106w depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not installed.
dpkg: error processing epson-inkjet-printer-201106w (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201106w

Comment: I would check with Epson, and see if there's anything special about installing the driver.